# What's the correct way to deal with multiple inheritence of modules sharing a common "ancestor" in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, lwp-useragent

(The Moose/Moo answer is, of course, "Roles". This question is about the general case where you want to combine two modules that are both subclasses of the same parent, assuming no Moose/Moo.)

Let's take a slightly contrived example: the modules [`LWP::UserAgent::Determined`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent::Determined) and [`LWP::RobotUA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::RobotUA) are both subclasses of [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) and extend it in different ways. What should I do if I want to create an object that combines the methods from both? It will, at its core, still be a `LWP::UserAgent` object, and the other two modules don't clash with each other, so it should be easy, right?

As far as I can tell, the correct thing to do is to create a new package which declares both of the other two as parents – `use parent qw(LWP::RobotUA LWP::UserAgent::Determined)` – and then create objects from that. And, indeed, if you do that, you get an object that contains the methods from both, as well as from the base class `LWP::UserAgent`, and *almost* everything works as you'd expect.

But not quite. Both `LWP::UserAgent::Determined` and `LWP::RobotUA` have default values for certain attributes that are set when the object is created if no other value is given. When combining the two, `LWP::RobotUA`'s defaults get set, but *not* `LWP::UserAgent::Determined`'s. So something must be wrong.

Here's some test code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

use LWP::RobotUA;
use LWP::UserAgent::Determined;

package MyUA;
use parent qw(LWP::RobotUA LWP::UserAgent::Determined);

for my $module (qw(LWP::RobotUA LWP::UserAgent::Determined MyUA)) {
    say '# ', $module, ' #';
    my $ua = $module->new(
                          'agent' => 'Test-UA',
                          'from'  => 'example@example.com',
                         );
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/emp/network_status.txt');
    my $response = $ua->request($req);
    unless ($module eq 'LWP::UserAgent::Determined') {
        say 'Use sleep? : ', $ua->use_sleep() // 'not defined!';
        say 'Allowed OK? : ', $ua->rules->allowed('https://www.bbc.co.uk/') // 'not defined!';
        say 'Sites with rules: ', (defined $ua->rules()->{loc}) ? join(', ', (sort keys %{$ua->rules()->{loc}})) : 'not defined!';
    }
    unless ($module eq 'LWP::RobotUA') {
        print 'Timings: ';
        if (defined $ua->timing()) {
            say $ua->timing();
        }
        else {
            print 'Timing defaults not set! ';
            $ua->timing('1,5,10,20,60,240');
            say '...but the method works: ', $ua->timing();
        }
        say 'Retry codes: ', (defined $ua->codes_to_determinate()) ? join(', ', (sort keys %{$ua->codes_to_determinate()})) : 'not defined!';
    }
    say '#'x60;
}
```

This outputs:

```
    # LWP::RobotUA #
    Use sleep? : 1
    Allowed OK? : 1
    Sites with rules: www.bbc.co.uk:443
    ############################################################
    # LWP::UserAgent::Determined #
    Timings: 1,3,15
    Retry codes: 408, 500, 502, 503, 504
    ############################################################
    # MyUA #
    Use sleep? : 1
    Allowed OK? : 1
    Sites with rules: www.bbc.co.uk:443
    Timings: Timing defaults not set! ...but the method works: 1,5,10,20,60,240
    Retry codes: not defined!
    ############################################################
```

Here you can see that the methods for both modules work, but default values are not set for `LWP::UserAgent::Determined`'s `timing()` or `codes_to_determinate()` methods when combined with `LWP::RobotUA`, while `LWP::RobotUA`'s `use_sleep()` method *is* created with its default value of `1`. Setting values manually works fine, however, and otherwise the combined object works as expected.

So, in summary: what's the correct way of handling this case, where you want to combine two modules that subclass a common third? Is this, in fact, correct, but I just chose an unfortunate example and `LWP::UserAgent::Determined` isn't well-behaved in how it sets it's defaults?

Comment: I haven't read any of the code yet, but I suspect neither of the `new` methods have a call to `SUPER` or similar. So half the code doesn't get called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your new class effectively looks like this:

```
package MyUA;

use parent qw(LWP::RobotUA LWP::UserAgent::Determined);

1;
```

Let's test it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use MyUA;

my $ua = MyUA->new(
  agent => 'test',
  from  => 'me@example.com',
);

say ref $ua;
```

That tells us that we have "MyUA" object. But what is it really? What have we made?

Well, objects are build using a constructor method. That's (usually) called `new()`. In this case, you haven't defined a `new()` method in your class. So Perl will look for the method in the superclasses. It does that by searching the classes it finds in `@INC` and seeing if each one, in turn, contains a `new()` method.

Both of your superclasses have a `new()` method. But Perl only needs one. So when it finds one, it stops looking and calls that method. The first one it calls is the one in LWP::RobotUA (because that's the first one on the list passed to `use parent`). So that one gets called.

This means that what you've *actually* got here is an object of class LWP::RobotUA. Well, mostly. It's been blessed into the right class and if you call any methods that are in LWP::UserAgent::Determined, but not in LWP::RobotUA, it will still work. But none of the LWP::UserAgent::Determined initialisation code has been called.

And that's a pretty good demonstration of why multiple inheritance is a bad idea. It's so hard to get it right in all but the most trivial of cases.

I can't give you an answer here. Because only you know which bits of the two superclasses you need. But the solution will involve adding your own `new()` method to your class and probably calling the two superclass constructors from within that.

**Update:** Ok, I've had a closer look. And it might be easier than I thought.

`LWP::RobotUA::new()` makes a call to `LWP::UserAgent::new()` in the middle of doing various other things. But `LWP::UserAgent::Determined::new()` makes a call to `LWP::UserAgent::new()` at the start of its processing and then helpfully bundles all of its other initialisation up in a separate method called `_determined_init()`.

So it looks like your solution could be a simple as adding a constructor method like this:

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);
  $self->_determined_init();

  return $self;
}
```

The call to `$class->SUPER::new()` calls `LWP::RobotUA::new()` because that's the first class in `@INC`. That, in turn, calls `LWP::UserAgent::new()` - so that initialisation is all done. We then just have to call `_determined_init()` in order to initialise the other superclass.

It seems to work in my (very basic) testing. But I'm still very dubious about multiple inheritance :-)

**Update 2:** Yes. [ikegami is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68288464/7231). My solution only fixes the problems with constructing the object. I didn't look into actually using it.

Comment: You can easily fudge a solution for `new`, but it's a bit tricker for `simple_request`. See my answer for a solution.

Comment: "But I'm still very dubious about multiple inheritance :-)"
 
To be clear, the question is not meant to in any way endorse multiple inheritence, and it's not something I would ever to use in any serious context! (I said it was a contrived example. ) It was more that I was reading the docs, and it sounded like it *should* work – even if you *shouldn't* do it! – and it almost did. And then I wanted to know why.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because it neatly addresses the example in question (lucky for `LWP::UserAgent::Determined` that it uses `_determined_init()`!) but I've benefited a lot from reading both yours and ikegami's answer together. Thank you!

Comment: Re "*I'm accepting this answer, because it neatly addresses the example in question*", It does not. It gives a solution that constructs the object properly (just like my solution), but the object doesn't work. You'll need my solution for that.  That Dave's solution doesn't work is the whole reason I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 4):

That can't work without changes to LWP::UA::Determined and/or LWP::RobotUA.

But those changes can be applied through monkey patching. A solution is presented at the bottom.

---

**The Problem**

LWP::UA::Determined wraps `->simple_request`, which is to say it provides a `->simple_request` which calls `->SUPER::simple_request` (which is `->LWP::UA::simple_request`)

LWP::RobotUA wraps `->simple_request`, which is to say it provides a `->simple_request` which calls `->SUPER::simple_request` (which is `->LWP::UA::simple_request`)

When you call `->request`, you'll end up calling `->simple_request`. Depending on the order of the modules in `@ISA`, this will call either `LWP::UA::Determined::simple_request` (and then `LWP::UA::simple_request`) or `LWP::RobotUA::simple_request` (and then `LWP::UA::simple_request`).

It will not call both `LWP::UA::Determined::simple_request` and `LWP::RobotUA::simple_request`. And it wouldn't work if it did because that would end up calling `LWP::UA::simple_request` twice.

The exact same problem exists for `->new`.

Demo

```perl
use feature qw( say );

{ package Base;
  sub method { say __PACKAGE__; } }

{ package SubA; our @ISA = qw( Base ); 
  sub method { say __PACKAGE__; $_[0]->SUPER::method(); } }

{ package SubB; our @ISA = qw( Base ); 
  sub method { say __PACKAGE__; $_[0]->SUPER::method(); } }

{ package SubAB; our @ISA = qw( SubA SubB ); }

SubAB->method();  # SubA Base
```

---

**The Solution**

LWP::UA::Determined and LWP::RobotUA would need to use [`next::method`](https://metacpan.org/pod/mro#next::method) instead of `SUPER` (or they would need to be designed entirely differently) for this to even have a chance of working.

Demo

```perl
use feature qw( say );

{ package Base;
  sub method { say __PACKAGE__; } }

{ package SubA; use mro 'c3'; our @ISA = qw( Base );
  sub method { say __PACKAGE__; $_[0]->next::method(); } }

{ package SubB; use mro 'c3'; our @ISA = qw( Base );
  sub method { say __PACKAGE__; $_[0]->next::method(); } }

{ package SubAB; use mro 'c3'; our @ISA = qw( SubA SubB ); }

SubAB->method();  # SubA SubB Base
```

---

**The Workaround**

All hope isn't lost! We can monkey patch LWP::UA::Determined and LWP::RobotUA to get the desired behaviour!

Simply add this to your program:

```perl
use LWP::RobotUA qw( );
BEGIN {
   package LWP::RobotUA::Inserted;
   use mro 'c3';
   our @ISA = @LWP::RobotUA::ISA;
   sub new            { return $_[0]->next::method(); }
   sub simple_request { return $_[0]->next::method(); }
   sub agent          { return $_[0]->next::method(); }
   @LWP::RobotUA::ISA = __PACKAGE__;
}

use LWP::UserAgent::Determined qw( );
BEGIN {
   package LWP::UserAgent::Determined::Inserted;
   use mro 'c3';
   our @ISA = @LWP::UserAgent::Determined::ISA;
   sub new            { return $_[0]->next::method(); }
   sub simple_request { return $_[0]->next::method(); }
   @LWP::UserAgent::Determined::ISA = __PACKAGE__;
}
```

You also need `use mro 'c3';` in your own class (or choose the order of `@ISA` carefully) for `->agent` to work correctly.

Demo

```perl
# Insert code from first demo here.

{ package SubA::Inserted; use mro 'c3'; our @ISA = @SubA::ISA;
  sub method { return $_[0]->next::method(); }
  @SubA::ISA = __PACKAGE__; }

{ package SubB::Inserted; use mro 'c3'; our @ISA = @SubB::ISA;
  sub method { return $_[0]->next::method(); }
  @SubB::ISA = __PACKAGE__; }

SubAB->method();  # SubA SubB Base
```

Comment: I regret that I can only accept one answer, because it feels like yours and Dave's together cover everything comprehensivly. Thank you, I've learned a lot here!

Comment: But Dave's answer doesn't provide a solution X_X